# REACT Uncaught TypeError .then is not a function

Tags: reactjs, promise, redux, react-router

i'm doing function in my react component like this :

```
const Logged = (props) => {

  const doLogout = () => {
    props.logout().then(() => browserHistory.push('/'));
  }

  return(
    <IconMenu
      {...Props}
      iconButtonElement={
        <IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
      }
      targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
      anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
    >
      <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" 
        onTouchTap={doLogout}
      />
    </IconMenu>
  )
};
```

i already wrap the dispatch in the component and connect it.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        logout: () => (
            dispatch(logoutUser)
        )
    }
}
```

this is my action:

```
export function logoutUser(){
    return (dispatch) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => { 
            dispatch({
                type    : LOGOUT_USER,
            });
            resolve();
        })
    }
};
```

and this is my reducer :

```
case LOGOUT_USER :  
            return Object.assign({}, state, {autenticated : false});
```

i always got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: props.logout(...).then is not a function
>       at Object.doLogout [as onTouchTap] (eval at

Comment: What does `dispatch` return in `dispatch(logoutUser)`?

Comment: @Bergi A promise?

Comment: Well, doesn't look like it, no. Is there any documentation about `dispatch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        logout: logoutUser(dispatch)
    };
}
```

```
export function logoutUser(dispatch) {
    return () => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => { 
            dispatch({
                type: LOGOUT_USER,
            });
            resolve();
        });
    };
}
```

Although it doesn't look like there's anything asynchronous happening, so no reason to wait for anything.

Comment: thx a lot. it work. but i still don't get it, could you explain me a bit why it doesn't work before. in my vs code i see my action logoutUser would return promise. and i'm doing async because it need to change the authentication to false then redirect it to "/" ,is there a better way?@Bergi

Comment: In your code `logoutUser` does not return a promise, but a function; and it's not even called, but only passed to `dispatch` (whose result does get returned, and is not a promise).