# React Redux promise error - (...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

Had a look for this in the questions that offered but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081085/react-uncaught-typeerror-then-is-not-a-function) was the closest and it didnt really address my problem.

I have a code block (detailed a little way down the page) as part of a larger fetch block.. it gets to this codeblock and also runs fine if this code block is commented out i.e it carrys out a successful fetch etc and returns a JWT no problem but... add this block in and i get the following error:

> TypeError: (0 , _localStorageDropDowns.confirmSelectDataExistance)(...).then is not a function

It is referring to this function in another folder (imported correctly)..

```
export const confirmSelectDataExistance = () => {
  const companyStateShortNameJson = localStorage.getItem(COMPANYSTATESHORTNAME)
  const statesJson = localStorage.getItem(STATES)
  const suburbLocationsJson = localStorage.getItem(LOCATIONS)
  if (companyStateShortNameJson || statesJson || suburbLocationsJson) {
    console.log('something exists in localstorage')
    return true
  }
    console.log('nothing in localstorage')
  return false
}
```

simple function - returns true or false.

and here is the code block -its failing on the first line:

```
    return confirmSelectDataExistance().then(isConfirmed => {
      if (!isConfirmed) {
        dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })
        console.log('gets here!', isConfirmed)
        const token = getJwt()
        const headers = new Headers({
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        })
        const retrieveSelectData = fetch('/api/SelectData/SelectData', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
          },
        })
          .then(handleErrors)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(selectData => {
            dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: selectData })
            saveSelectData(selectData)
          });

        return saveSelectData(selectData);
      }
    })
```

From my limited experience the "confirmSelectDataExistance" is a function so why is it saying that its not?

Finally here is the whole action in its entirety so you can see how it that block is called.. as I said - comment the block out and it works perfectly..

```
export const requestLoginToken = (username, password) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: username })

    const payload = {
      userName: username,
      password: password,
    }

    const task = fetch('/api/jwt', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
    })
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: data })
        saveJwt(data)

        return confirmSelectDataExistance().then(isConfirmed => {
          if (!isConfirmed) {
            dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })
            console.log('gets here!', isConfirmed)
            const token = getJwt()
            const headers = new Headers({
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            })
            const retrieveSelectData = fetch('/api/SelectData/SelectData', {
              method: 'GET',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
              },
            })
              .then(handleErrors)
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(selectData => {
                dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: selectData })
                saveSelectData(selectData)
              });

            return saveSelectData(selectData);
          }
        })

      })
      .catch(error => {
        clearJwt()
        console.log('ERROR - LOGIN!',error)
      })
    addTask(task)
    return task
  }
```

**EDIT**

I have finally got this to work after hacking away for hours.. Here is the finished action:

```
export const requestLoginToken = (username, password) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: username })

    const payload = {
      userName: username,
      password: password,
    }

    const task = fetch('/api/jwt', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
    })
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: data })
        saveJwt(data)

        // Now check local storage for dropdown data..
        if (!confirmSelectDataExistance()) {
          dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })
          const token = JSON.stringify(data)
          const headers = new Headers({
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
          })
          const retrieveSelectData = fetch('/api/SelectData/SelectData', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
          })
            .then(handleErrors)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(selectData => {
              dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: selectData })
              saveSelectData(selectData)
            });

        }
      })

      .catch(error => {
        clearJwt()
        console.log('ERROR - LOGIN!', error)
      })
    addTask(task)
    return task
  }
```

and here is the function it calls:

```
export const confirmSelectDataExistance = () => {
  const companyStateShortNameJson = localStorage.getItem(COMPANYSTATESHORTNAME)
  const statesJson = localStorage.getItem(STATES)
  const suburbLocationsJson = localStorage.getItem(LOCATIONS)
  if (companyStateShortNameJson || statesJson || suburbLocationsJson) {
    console.log('something exists in localstorage')
    return true
  }
    console.log('nothing in localstorage')
  return false
}
```

The one thing I changed from the other attempts is that I used "data" instead of calling "getJwt()". I then used the line:

```
const token = JSON.stringify(data)
```

to obtain the JWT I just got.

In the end I used @Karin s answer and ran with that. (upvoted by me)

Comment: `confirmSelectDataExistance` needs to return a `Promise` if you want to use `then`.

Comment: How is this suppose to be structured so it works..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not saying that `confirmSelectDataExistance` is not a function, it's saying that `then` isn't a function on what is returned from it, which is a boolean (it would be equivalent to `false.then(...)`, which doesn't work).

If seems like you're trying to use `then` as a conditional. In that case a simple `if` statement should work:

```
if (confirmSelectDataExistance()) {
    // do things if it returns true
} else {
    // do things if it returns false
}
```

Comment: Tried this solution and got the same error as below :( "TypeError: (0 , _localStorageDropDowns.confirmSelectDataExistance) is not a function
    at reducer.js:43" ... its still says that my function is not a function...

Comment: Are you confident the function is imported correctly? It is difficult to tell what's wrong without looking at the code attempt.

Comment: Glad it's working! In general you don't need to use Promises unless you require a callback (usually when something happens asynchronously). Since your `confirmSelectDataExistance` method wasn't issuing an AJAX call or anything, it seemed overkill to use Promises for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
export const confirmSelectDataExistance = () => {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

  const companyStateShortNameJson = localStorage.getItem(COMPANYSTATESHORTNAME)
  const statesJson = localStorage.getItem(STATES)
  const suburbLocationsJson = localStorage.getItem(LOCATIONS)
  if (companyStateShortNameJson || statesJson || suburbLocationsJson) {
    console.log('something exists in localstorage')
    resolve(true)
  }
  console.log('nothing in localstorage')
  reject(false)
 })
}
```

Comment: I did get it to work as per my edit but I think this would also work although I have nt tried it... so relieved the bl%^dy thing is working!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
export const confirmSelectDataExistance = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const companyStateShortNameJson = localStorage.getItem(COMPANYSTATESHORTNAME);
  const statesJson = localStorage.getItem(STATES);
  const suburbLocationsJson = localStorage.getItem(LOCATIONS);
  if (companyStateShortNameJson || statesJson || suburbLocationsJson) {
    console.log('something exists in localstorage');
    resolve(true);
  }
    console.log('nothing in localstorage');
  reject(false); // or resolve(false) if you want handle this situation inside then block also
});
```

Comment: added this and got this error: "localStorageDropDowns.js: Unexpected token, expected ; " and its indicating its on the  " => " just after the reject.

Comment: remove space after "Promise" before "("

Comment: try please again, i wrap the promise to ()